# easeljs not working on Android 2

Tags: javascript, android, easeljs

I had made a Jigsaw Puzzle in RaphaelJS but found that it did not work on Android 2x as SVG support in default browser is only available after Android 3x versions.

Because of this I was looking for suitable HTML5 Javascript Library alternative with Drag & Drop capability so that I can built Jigsaw Puzzle in it. EaselJS looks very promising but when I try to play the Drag & Drop demo on its website http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/dragdrop it does not work and all I can see is a red block in Android Browser.

Can you please help me identify proper JS Library that would work in Android 2.x environment ?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does not work because Canvas.toDataURL is not implemented in early Android versions. See here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901. You can find workarounds if you want to support Android that does not have this API.